# SQL Query - Narrow down by count

Tags: sql

I have the following table and need to narrow down to the names who have a higher book count than DVD count.

[image: table]

any ideas?  My trouble is some have just one entry..and then removing the ones with two who have higher DVD then books.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: How should the ones be treated, that have only one type? Could they be treated as if they had zero from the other type? Or should they be excluded? And what if the counts are equal for both types? Include such customers or not?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
select t.name
from t
where t.type = 'DVD' and
      t.count > (select t2.count
                 from t t2
                 where t2.name = t.name and t2.type = 'Book'
                );
```

An alternative uses aggregation and `having`:

```
select t.name
from t
group by t.name
having max(case when t.type = 'DVD' then count end) > max(case when t.type = 'Book' then count end);
```